# In the Recursion Theorem, does obtaining a description of SELF increase the length of the program?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

In the following video, he mentions that x <- <SELF> (x obtaining a description of itself) is a "legal" operation for a Turing Machine to make. https://youtu.be/5yO_l2w0wIA?t=93

My question is, what is the description length of x with and without that 'line' of code? Does obtaining the description of x double the length of the description of x, because it's basically 'baked in' to x, or does x 'compute' its own description without needing to have it written down anywhere else?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29

Answer (score 0):

The following is a CPP code for a program that prints its own code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
        cout << "#include <iostream> \n using namespace std; \n int main(){ \n  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){ \n cout << WOW! it is printing its own code! << endl; \n } \n return 0; \n } \n\n\n" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And you may find some challenges about the SELF programs like [this](https://www.cprogramming.com/challenges/solutions/self_print.html) with some [solutions](http://www.nyx.net/%7Egthompso/quine.htm). If you are interested in its theory aspect you may read Lemma 6.1 in [Introduction to the theory of computation](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Computatio/1aMKAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover).
So, if I want to answer your title question, yes I believe the program that has the ability to obtain its source code may have a longer code.

Comment: I think that your quine is not correct.